# Futz Gunshot Question

Tags: gunshot, sfx, futz

I am currently editing SFX for a trailer. There is a scene in the trailer where the lead character opens fire, but we see this through a video camera that he is using to record what he sees. The question I have is that is there any point in adding multiple layers (like low frequency hits) for the gunshot if its gonna be futz later on? Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the only place you're ever seeing/hearing that shot from is the video camera, I would make it sound like that. I wouldn't personally make a hollywood gun for that.

Answer (score 1):

That could depend on the impact and POV you'd like to achieve. 
Sound tells what the visuals cannot. 
The character may be looking through the camera, but he's still hearing from his own ears, I assume(?).
Without knowing the trailer, I would ask myself these questions:
Is the entire trailer seen through the camera?
Is it clear that it must exist a distinction between his POV and some other's?
What happens before and after? Do you need to enhance any contrast between scenes?